# isotopy equivalence of maps

Tags: functions, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology, fiber-bundles

In the book [Encyclopaedia of Mathematics, Vol. 6,](https://books.google.com/books?isbn=9400903650)

[image]

**Question:** I do not understand the part
[image]

Does this mean $F_1\circ f_0=f_1: X\to Y$ or as subsets of $Y$,
$$
\{y\in F_1(f_0(X))\}=\{y\in f_1(X)\}?
$$

Comment: I think you should just read wikipedia article.... it seems to make this much more clear: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy#Isotopy

Comment: The literal reading of that equation would suggest that the 2nd alternative is what the author intends. I would not spend too much time on trying to figure this out, though. The terminology in this passage is out-dated and this particular notion of "isotopy equivalence" is not very important, I think.